# How to return a string which repeats the phrases ("go for it" , "don´t do it") a specific number of times and returns the last phrase in caps?

Tags: javascript, function

example:

doIt(1) ➞  "DO IT"

doIt(3) ➞ "do it, don't do it, DO IT"

doIt(2) ➞ "do it, DON'T DO IT"

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: sorry, first time i use the site and I have no previous coding experience. I'll check it

Comment: At some point all of us had no coding experience. Part of the fun of coding is that you solve problems by yourself.

Comment: any tips? i don't even know where to look for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const repeastPhrases = (num) => {
  const phrases = ["go for it", "don't do it"];
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    result += i === num - 1 ? phrases[0].toUpperCase() : `${phrases[0]}, ${phrases[1]}, `;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(repeastPhrases(4));
```

Comment: thanks. But I made a mistake when asking. Every sentence should be by itself., so each repetition would be just "do it" or "don´t do it", not both at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand too well. Do you mean the function should return either "do it" or "don't do it"? But the function should not return something like: "do it, don't do it, DO IT"?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript as in python the work with strings is super ease, try this(by the way, this is javascript):

```
let doit = 'do it';
        let dontdi = 'don\'t do it';
        
        function doIt(n){
            let i = 1;
            let phrase = '';
            
            while(i<=n){                
                if(i%2 != 0){                   
                    phrase += (i==n)?(doit.toUpperCase()):(doit);
                    phrase += ', ';
                }else{
                    phrase += (i==n)?(dontdi.toUpperCase()):(dontdi);
                    phrase += ', ';
                }
                
                i++;
            }
            
            return phrase.slice(-phrase.lenght,-2);
        }
        
        console.log(doIt(2));//do it, DON'T DO IT
        console.log(doIt(3));//do it, don't do it, DO IT
        console.log(doIt(5));//do it, don't do it, do it, don't do it, DO IT
        console.log(doIt(8));//do it, don't do it, do it, don't do it, do it, don't do it, do it, DON'T DO IT
```